# Bash array and loop won't work together

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, if-statement

I am pretty new in bash script and can't figure out why this piece of code doesn't work (yes I've googled around).

Here's my code:

```
if [ $usertype = normal ]
then
    commands[0]="hi" ; descriptions[0]="get greeted"
    commands[1]="test" ; descriptions[1] = "test"
elif [ $usertype = hacker ]
    commands[0]="hi" ; descriptions[0]="get greeted"
    commands[1]="test" ; descriptions[1] = "test"
fi

alias fhelp='
for ((i=0; i<=${commands[@]}; i++))
do
    printf '%s %s\n' "${commands[i]}" "${descriptions[i]}"
done'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: @AdamLiss The terminal says there's a "syntax error near unexpected token `fi' "...

Comment: `printf '%s %s\n' "${commands[i]}" "${descriptions[i]}"` can be replaced using `echo "${commands[i]} ${descriptions[i]}"` -- much cleaner and better.

Comment: @Bill The thing is I need the two arrays to be printed side by side. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: What you have looks correct to me, given both arrays are of equal length. I recommend to use `echo` instead of `printf`. Pls see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quotes inside single quotes. Do this, it treats `"'"` as a string of a single quote and concatenate them.

```
alias fhelp='
for ((i=0; i<=${commands[@]}; i++))
do
  printf '"'"'%s %s\n'"'"' "${commands[i]}" "${descriptions[i]}"
done'
```

And use `${#commands[@]}` to get the array length.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
elif [ $usertype = hacker ]
# missing then!
commands[0]="hi" ; descriptions[0]="get greeted"
```

Comment: Now it says "-bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

But yeah I can't believe I forgot the "then"

Comment: You should put all variables in quotes.

Comment: it is good to use `elif [ "$usertype" = hacker ]` instead of `elif [ $usertype = hacker ]`

Comment: also `hacker` should be `"hacker"` and same for `normal`